# Why and for what does one need the generatedKeys of a surrogate key of a Database?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Postgres database and I'm writing a Java program that will query,
insert,
update,
and delete data from it.
Some of my tables have surrogate keys,
which the DB auto-increments.

I use the `getGeneratedKeys()` method to receive the key of the last inserted tuple.
But I don't understand why I need these keys and what to do with them?

I am able to insert the data without receiving these keys.

```
// Works as expected and gives me the last key.
PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
....
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next()) {
                this.lastID = rs.getInt(1);
            }
```

What is the purpose and/or value of these generated keys?

Comment: For example, you might want to use that generated key to do something else, such as insert a record into another table.

Comment: You mean as foreign key in another table?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by my example, though there are probably other examples of why you want to get generated keys from Java.

Comment: Maybe you want to return a link to a new resource in an HTTP `Location` header.

Comment: Even without any other table: suppose the client needs the value of this generated ID in order to store it somewhere and get the row values later.

Comment: Thanks, your examples make totally sense. Just wasn't thinking about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert to more than 1 table which have foreign key to another table.

You will need the key referenced to be inserted and then also in the foreign key column of the second table.

Table A's id foreign key of Table B's id

Insert table B and use same Id when insert to Table A

Comment: For example, to store an invoice with three line items, you first write the invoice (parent) and capture its generated primary key value. Then you write each of the three line items in the line-item child table, assigning to each new line item row the identifier of its parent invoice (its foreign key).